# Ассоциативный массив и его элементы

Tags: python

Дело таково: есть Ассоциативный Массив надо узнать ключ по его порядковому номеру.

Помогите ПЖ!

Comment: Немного странный вопрос к автору: будь Вы интерпретатором, как бы Вы сами определили порядковый номер ключа ассоциативного массива? Вот, допустим, есть у нас `{1: 2, 2: 4, 9: 55}`, какой ключ здесь первый? `1: 2`? А если принять во внимание, что, записав массив так `{9: 55, 1: 2, 2: 4}`, мы ничего не изменим? Веду к тому, что **у ключей ассоциативного массива нет порядковых номеров хотя бы потому, что не понятно, как определить их порядок относительно друг друга**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = {'a':'a1', 'b':'b1','c':'c1'}
print(list(result)[1]) #получить индекс второго элемента(Нумерация начинается с нуля)
```